# How to keep records of multiple previous frames in video processing

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I currently working on lane detection for autonomous vehicles using opencv and python. I have used houghline transform to get lines in the road. From those lines I have calculated the mean slope and intercept values separately for the lines which have negative and positive slopes. To reduce errors, I want to keep track of calculated mean slopes and intercepts of previous 3 frames. So that I can check the deviance of mean slope and intercept values of current frame and correct it accordingly. Is there a way to keep track of 3 previous frames ?

this is I have done up to now. This is for the current frame. I want to keep calculated mean values up to 3 previous frames and access those values form current frame.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video3.mov')

while (cap.isOpened()):

  ret, frame = cap.read() 
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

  # HSL color mask
  lower_white = np.uint8([0, 140, 0])
  upper_white = np.uint8([255, 255, 255])
  mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

  height = np.size(hsv, 0)
  width = np.size(hsv, 1)

  rows, cols = hsv.shape[:2]

  bottom_left = [cols * 0, rows * 0.9]
  top_left = [cols * 0.4, rows * 0.7]
  bottom_right = [cols * 1, rows * 0.9]
  top_right = [cols * 0.6, rows * 0.7]

  vertices = np.array([[bottom_left, top_left, top_right, bottom_right]], dtype=np.int32)

  maskzero = np.zeros_like(res)
  cv2.fillPoly(maskzero, vertices, (255,) * maskzero.shape[2])
  maskedimg = cv2.bitwise_and(res, maskzero)

  # smoothed = cv2.medianBlur(maskedimg,3)
  gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(maskedimg, (3, 3), 0)

  # apply canny on masked image
  cannymask = cv2.Canny(gaussian, 150, 250)

  # apply hough transform houghlinesP
  lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cannymask, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=20, minLineLength=10, maxLineGap=300)

  left_slope = []
  right_slope = []
  left_intercept = []
  right_intercept = []
  total_right_length = []
  total_left_length = []

  if lines is not None:
      for line in lines:
         for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:

            if (x2 - x1) != 0:
                slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
                intercept = y1 - slope * x1
                length = np.sqrt((y2 - y1) ** 2 + (x2 - x1) ** 2)
                angle = math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)
                degree = angle * 180 / np.pi

           if x2 == x1 or y2 == y1:
               continue

           elif slope > 0:
              if int(degree) in range (27,41):
                 right_slope.append(slope)
                 right_intercept.append(intercept)
                 total_right_length.append(length)
              angle = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
              degree = angle * 180 / np.pi
              print("positive",degree)

        elif slope < 0:
            if int(degree) in range (-62,-31):
                left_slope.append(slope)
                left_intercept.append(intercept)
                total_left_length.append(length)
            angle = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
            degree = angle * 180 / np.pi
            print("negative",degree)
            degreeint= int(degree)
            #cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

  sum_right_length = np.sum(total_right_length) if len(total_right_length) > 0 else None
  right_mean_slope=np.mean(right_slope) if len(right_slope)>0 else None
  right_mean_intercept=np.mean(right_intercept) if len(right_intercept) > 0 else None

  sum_left_length = np.sum(total_left_length) if len(total_left_length) > 0 else None
  left_mean_slope = np.mean(left_slope) if len(left_slope)>0 else None
  left_mean_intercept = np.mean(left_intercept) if len(left_intercept) > 0 else None

  right_x1=0
  right_y1=0
  right_x2=0
  right_y2=0

  left_x1=0
  left_x2=0
  left_y2=0
  left_y1=0

  y1 = frame.shape[0] # bottom of the image
  y2 = y1*0.7
  if right_mean_intercept is not None and right_mean_slope is not None:
     right_x1 = int((y1 - right_mean_intercept)/right_mean_slope)
     right_x2 = int((y2 - right_mean_intercept)/right_mean_slope)
     right_y1 = int(y1)
     right_y2 = int(y2)
 if left_mean_intercept is not None and left_mean_slope is not None:
     left_x1 = int((y1 - left_mean_intercept)/left_mean_slope)
     left_x2 = int((y2 - left_mean_intercept)/left_mean_slope)
     left_y1 = int(y1)
     left_y2 = int(y2)

  cv2.line(frame, (right_x1, right_y1), (right_x2, right_y2), (0, 0, 255), 10)
  cv2.line(frame, (left_x1, left_y1), (left_x2, left_y2), (255, 0,0), 10)
  cv2.imshow("New_lines", frame)

if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to keep right and left mean slope and intercept values of 3 previous frames and access them from the current frame.

Comment: choose a data structure and put them inside? `old = {}`  `old[framenumber]  = [ [your right values], [your left values],[your intercept values] ]` and clear out any framenumber thats lower then the `actual-3` to keep memory low?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video3.mov')

previous = [ ]   # We will keep track of previous 3 frames in this list
while (cap.isOpened()):

  ret, frame = cap.read() 
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
  if len(previous) == 3 :
       # do your thing like calculating the mean
       for x in range(3):
           print(previous[x])   # This is how you can access the previous frames

       # ================================================================
       # After you are done add the below two lines of code 
       # Below two lines are necessary to keep track of recent 3 frames
       # ================================================================
       previous = previous[1:]  # Removing the first frame so now length of previous is 2
       previous.append(frame)   # Adding the current frame so length of previous is 3 again
  else : 
       # else condition is for if frames are less then 3
       # else condition is for the very beginning when you previous will start with empty list 
       previous.append(frame)
       continue # If you want to do computation even when length of previous is less than 3 than comment the continue statement 
if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner else is for the contion frames are less than 3

Comment: you append a frame in the `if`, you append a frame in the `else`- so its done either way?

Comment: If you see in `if` I am also removing the first frame.... so that makes sure my previous is always of 3

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video3.mov')

prevFrames = [None,None,None] # avoid index mishaps for [-1]..[-3] 
                              # you need to test for None when accessing
while (cap.isOpened()):

  ret, frame = cap.read() 
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

  # [...]


  # access prevFrames[-1] for last frame, 
  #                  [-2] for the one before that, 
  #                  [-3] for the one 3 before now 
  #                  check value for None before using


  sum_right_length = np.sum(total_right_length) if len(total_right_length) > 0 else None
  right_mean_slope=np.mean(right_slope) if len(right_slope)>0 else None
  right_mean_intercept=np.mean(right_intercept) if len(right_intercept) > 0 else None

  sum_left_length = np.sum(total_left_length) if len(total_left_length) > 0 else None
  left_mean_slope = np.mean(left_slope) if len(left_slope)>0 else None
  left_mean_intercept = np.mean(left_intercept) if len(left_intercept) > 0 else None

  # [...]

  # add data from current frame at end
  prevFrames.append( [right_mean_slope, left_mean_slope, right_mean_intercept, left_mean_intercept ] 

  if len(prevFrames) > 3:
      prevFrames.pop(0)  # remove and discard oldest element


  cv2.line(frame, (right_x1, right_y1), (right_x2, right_y2), (0, 0, 255), 10)
  cv2.line(frame, (left_x1, left_y1), (left_x2, left_y2), (255, 0,0), 10)
  cv2.imshow("New_lines", frame)
```

Comment: Sad. another unconstructive -1. Giving feedback would be nice, I would learn how to get better that way.